# merging two indexed nested tables per unique value in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have this record type, a list of VARCHAR2 :

```
TYPE varchar2_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

In my PLSQL, I have two of these arrays, and I would like to merge them into a third array, per **unique** value. Something like :

```
DECLARE
    TYPE varchar2_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    foo    varchar2_array;
    bar    varchar2_array;
    foobar varchar2_array;
BEGIN

    foo(1) := '1';
    foo(2) := '2';
    foo(3) := '3';

    bar(1) := '2';
    bar(2) := '3';
    bar(3) := '4';

    foobar := unique_merge (foo, bar);

    FOR i IN 1 .. foobar.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('foobar(' || i || ') : ' || foobar(i));
    END LOOP;

    -- output : 1, 2, 3, 4

END;
```

I am looking for a simple way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Are the indexes of `foo` and `bar` important?  If so, I assume that the indexes of `foobar` would be important as well, in which case you'd need to explain how to determine that in general.  If the indexes are not important, why are you using an associative array rather than a nested table?

Comment: @AskAiser, did you see my answer? Is it good for you or do you expect something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try MULTISET UNION DISTINCT.
The solution could be something like

```
customer_list_3 := customer_list_2  MULTISET UNION DISTINCT customer_list_1
```

EDIT:

Ok, I did a mistrake, I didn't see this is not a nested table.

Here a possible impelmentation:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE VAR_TABLE_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10);
    TYPE varchar2_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    foo    varchar2_array;
    bar    varchar2_array;
    foobar varchar2_array;
    foobar_tmp VAR_TABLE_TYPE:= VAR_TABLE_TYPE() ;
    j number;
BEGIN

    foo(1) := '1';
    foo(2) := '2';
    foo(3) := '3';

    bar(1) := '2';
    bar(2) := '3';
    bar(3) := '4';

j:=foo.count;

for i in foo.first .. foo.last
  loop
              foobar_tmp.EXtend;
            foobar_tmp(i) :=  foo(i) ;
  end loop;

for i in bar.first .. bar.last
  loop
              foobar_tmp.EXtend;
            foobar_tmp(j+i) :=  bar(i) ;
  end loop;

  foobar_tmp :=  SET (foobar_tmp) ;

for i in foobar_tmp.first .. foobar_tmp.last
  loop
 foobar(i) :=  foobar_tmp(i) ;
  end loop;  


for i in foobar.first .. foobar.last
  loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('foobar(' || i || ') '||foobar(i));
    end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it throws "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MULTISET_UNION_DISTINCT'". I think it is because of the "INDEXED BY" clause.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. [Multiset operators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/operators006.htm) work with _nested tables_ as can be found from documentation: _Multiset operators combine the results of two nested tables into a single nested table._

Comment: @eliatou It works, and I learned a new operator (SET), thank you.